# How do you handle errors when using a service layer?

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception, software-design, service-layer

in my Zend Framework project, I use a Service Layer, however I don't really know where to handle errors.

For example, let's say I've a `UserService::updateUser($data);`

What if I've:

```
$data = array(
   'userId' => 2,
   'firstName' => 'Jane',
   'lastName'  => 'Doe',
);
```

And user with id 2 doesn't exist?

Where and how would you handle such errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can forward to a specific controller to handle all your business errors, like this :

```
if ($error=true)
        return $this->_forward('standarderror', 'businesserror', 'default',
                array('msgtitle' => $this->view->translate('item_not_found'),
                    'msg' => $this->view->translate('item_not_found_msg')));
```

and where your BusinesserrorController looks like :

```
class BusinesserrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

public function init() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
}

public function standarderrorAction() {
    $msgtitle = $this->_getParam('msgtitle');
    $msg = $this->_getParam('msg');

    $this->view->errortitle = $msgtitle;
    $this->view->errormessage = $msg;

    $this->view->nextstep = $this->view->translate('return_to_the_homepage');
    $this->view->nextstepurl = "/";

    echo $this->render('error/businesserror', null, true);
}

}
```

you can parametrize the forwarded url as well ;)